# Why doesn't awk exit at the end of this script?

Tags: bash, awk

This script doesn't terminate; it just hangs like it's waiting for more input. What am I missing?

```
echo 'foo bar baz q45' | awk '{ for(i=1;1<NF;i++) if($i ~ "q45") print $i; }'
```

prints `q45` as intended, but then just waits and I need to break out with Ctrl+c.

I'm pretty new to awk so sorry if this is an awk-ward way to write code. This is in Terminal on mac OS X 10.9.3 Mavericks, if that matters at all.

Comment: Bad pun; no cookie. I'm curious, though, as to your actual use case here -- generally, for this kind of thing, there'd be no need to use awk at all, as opposed to native bash builtins. For instance: `echo 'foo bar baz q45' | { read -a words; for word in "${words[@]}"; do [[ $word =~ q45 ]] && echo "$word"; done; }`

Comment: You've accidentally typed `1` where you mean `i` in the condition of your `for` loop.

Comment: ...yup, that's it. @ooga, add that as an answer?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Since it's just a typo, maybe we should encourage the OP to just delete the question?

Comment: That's because you need to make the condition `<=` not just `<`.

Comment: Since your error was virtually just a typo, you should probably delete this question.

Comment: Since someone's tried to horn in on my "answer", I've added one of my own. Choose which you will.

Comment: @ooga I can't delete it cause it has answers so I flagged it.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy this is part of a larger script that I was working on, I just narrowed the issue down to this and then got stuck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've accidentally typed `1` where you mean `i` in the condition of your for loop. Since 1 is always less than NF (in your case), you get an infinite loop. And you also need to make the condition `<=` not just `<` to go through all of the fields.
So your command should be:

```
echo 'foo bar baz q45' | awk '{ for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) if ($i ~ "q45") print $i; }'
```

Comment: So what you're saying is, it's time to stop working for today.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is this:

```
echo 'foo bar baz q45' | awk '{ for(i=1;1<NF;i++) if($i ~ "q45") print $i; }'
```

And the reason that loops is because `1<NF` makes no sense. Meaning the `for` loop would never end. To see this in action run it like this:

```
echo 'foo bar baz q45' | awk '{ for(i=1;1<NF;i++) print $i; }'
```

And watch the screen fill up with nothing! That `1` should be a `i` instead. And related to that, the `<` makes little sense as well. It should be `<=`. So the whole rewritten command would be:

```
echo 'foo bar baz q45' | awk '{ for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) if($i ~ "q45") print $i; }'
```